# Custom templating / ASCII conversion of hex values

Tags: go

I have a file which is a "template" in pure ASCII containing hex values represented like ex `\x0d\0a` for `CR\LF`.

A line in the file could look like this:

```
TEXT100\x1b\x03
```

I would like to convert this into a byte array ( so `0x1b` becomes 1 single byte - ASCII for ESC ) the simplest way in Go - is there any way this can be done without writing one that manually goes through each line from scratch?

Can the ASCII/templating module support or be adjusted to understand such a format?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [`strconv.Unquote`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote).

Comment: So there are no helper functions in that regard, have to write conversion manually like by line ?

Comment: Nothing forces you to do this line by line. You can also read the whole file and call Unquote once.

Comment: Ok ive seen GoValidator it wouldnt be an approach i should use this for ? ( i would need some other formatting too in regards to variable fields where i have {{unknown}} where i would need to test for start {{ and end }} and extract the content in the mifdle ( the variable name )